# How can I load same file into hive table using beeline

Tags: hive, beeline

I needed to create huge test data in hive table. I tried following commands but it only inserts one partition data at a time.

connect to beeline:

```
beeline --force=true -u 'jdbc:hive2://<host>:<port>/<hive database name>;ssl=true;user=<username>;password=<pw>'
```

create partitioned table :

```
CREATE TABLE p101(
Name string,
Age string)
PARTITIONED BY(fi string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

I have created ins.csv file with data and copy it to hdfs location, its data is as follows.

```
Name,Age
aaa,33
bbb,22
ccc,55
```

then I tried to load same file for multiple partition ids with following command

```
LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs_path/ins.csv' INTO TABLE p101 PARTITION(fi=1,fi=2,fi=3,fi=4,fi=5);
```

but it loads record only for partitionID=5.

Comment: did u tried loading the csv to a normal table and load it to the partition table using Insert into ?

Comment: yup, I just tried that one and it is working. thanks.

Comment: That's what I remember. we can't able to load csv directly to a partition table. As the data need to be separated based on partition.

Answer (score 1):

You can only specify one partition for each `insert into`.

What you can do in order to have different partitions is add it into your `csv file` like this:

```
Name,Age,fi
aaa,33,1
bbb,22,2
ccc,55,3
```

Hive will automatically know that this is the partition.

`LOAD DATA INPATH 'hdfs_path/ins.csv' INTO TABLE tmp.p101;`

Comment: hi Clover,  I have tried that before and I got error : Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10062]: Need to specify partition columns because the destination table is partitioned (state=42000,code=10062)

Comment: Hmm.. not sure why. May I know the Hive version that you're using? Also, does your CSV file got the partition column? This works  using Hive 3.1.0. Also, I changed the table to `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE`.

Comment: yup it does got partition column, It could be due to old version I just checked it Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.16.1.  
As of now I am using the approach @Roshan mentioned above.

Comment: oh glad you figured an alternative!

Comment: today I tried it on new env Hive 3.1.3000.7.1.7.48-2.  It was failing with 500/200 records, but worked with 100 records load.

Comment: Hi @user7220859, out of curiosity I tried csv with 500 records. It's still working on my Hive version.

Comment: not sure could be config setup.